# How to make navbar and its elements change based on hover and scrollY?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, navbar, parent-child

Hi I'm making a navbar that changes based on hover and `scrollY`.
Here are the requirements:

```
when scrollY > 0 (That means, navbar not on top):
    navbar bg-color -> "#fff"    
    children (a, i, p tags) color -> "#000"    
    when child hovered:
       child color -> "ff7bac" 
and that is whiteNavbar() function, it is done and it's working. now I need to do: 
when scrollY <= 0 (navbar on top):
    navbar bg-color -> rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
    children color -> "#fff"
    when navbar hovered:
        navbar bg-color -> "#fff"
        children color -> "#000"
    when child hovered:
        child color -> "ff7bac"
```

[when navbar and child hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC7Uz.png)
[when nothing hovered and scrollY <= 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs0Bs.jpg)
[when navbar hovered and scrollY <= 0 OR when scrollY > 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3PwY.png)

JS code:

```
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
let navbar_tags = navbar.querySelectorAll("p, i, a");
let navbar_products = document.querySelector('.navbar-products');
let children = [...navbar_tags, navbar_products];
let timeout_n;

function whiteNavbar() { 
    navbar.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    children.forEach(child => {
        child.style.color = "#000";
        child.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            this.style.color = "#ff7bac";
        });
        child.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            this.style.color = "#000";
        });
    });
}

function transparentNavbar() {
    
}

function changeNavbarColor() {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollY > 0) {
        whiteNavbar();
    }
    else {
        transparentNavbar();
    }
}


transparentNavbar();
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout_n);
    timeout_n = setTimeout(changeNavbarColor, 10);
});
```

At the beginning I had it done in CSS, but I had to switch to JS to add functionality when scrollY > 0
When doing it similarly to `whiteNavbar()` function everything works, besides that navbar event is overlapping a child event, and child color -> "ff7bac" stops working.
code:

```
function transparentNavbar() {
    navbar.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
    children.forEach(child => {
        child.style.color = "#fff";
        child.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            this.style.color = "#ff7bac";
        });
        child.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            this.style.color = "#fff";
        });
    });

    navbar.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        children.forEach(child => {
            child.style.color = "#000";
        });
    });

    navbar.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
        children.forEach(child => {
            child.style.color = "#fff";
        });
    });
}
```

This is the best version ^^, almost works besides child color -> "#77bac" when hovered

I tried `stopPropagation()` but then navbar hover bg-color change, stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify this logic with Css instead of relying completely on JS events. I would simply create a class and that class will be responsible for setting the styles for the navbar background, and child links.

As you have not provided the complete code, I have added a `position sticky` and `top: 0` to show the complete working example. Here is how you can do it.

```js
let timeout_n; // Define timeout_n variable

const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
const navbarTags = navbar.querySelectorAll("p, i, a");

function whiteNavbar() {
    navbar.classList.add('white-bg');
    navbarTags.forEach(child => {
        child.classList.add('white-text');
    });
}

function transparentNavbar() {
    navbar.classList.remove('white-bg');
    navbarTags.forEach(child => {
        child.classList.remove('white-text');
    });
}

function changeNavbarColor() {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollY > 0) {
        whiteNavbar();
    } else {
        transparentNavbar();
    }
}

transparentNavbar();

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_n);
    timeout_n = setTimeout(changeNavbarColor, 10);
});
```

```css
/* Initial styles for navbar */
.navbar {
    top:0;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
}

/* Styles when navbar is white */
.navbar.white-bg {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/* Styles for child elements when navbar is white */
.navbar.white-bg p,
.navbar.white-bg i,
.navbar.white-bg a {
    color: #000;
}

/* Hover styles for child elements when navbar is white */
.navbar p:hover, .navbar.white-bg p:hover,
.navbar i:hover, .navbar.white-bg i:hover,
.navbar a:hover, .navbar.white-bg a:hover {
    color: #ff7bac;
}

/* Hover styles for navbar when navbar is white */
.navbar.white-bg:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <i>Icon</i>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: real thanks, actually this is the best way, I tried to avoid that because I really hate css, but it's actually quite easy. again, thank you for help